# Download Pages From SharePoint for Deployment to Another SharePoint Site

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Are there any tools or methods I can use to pull down .aspx pages from SharePoint into Visual Studio?

I'm developing a SharePoint site on a development environment, for use in several other locations.  All of the content I create needs to be created programatically so I can quickly deploy and test on multiple locations.

I'm most familiar with SharePoint development using the site and SharePoint Designer.  I would like to be able to pull pages down that I've developed on the site, so I can then deploy those pages to other locations and make modifications in visual studio.

What I'm trying to avoid is creating features to custom-build every page on my site.  I'd much rather design pages the way I'm used to and then deploy them.

I understand that SharePoint 2010 uses ghosting and stores content in the database, so this may not be an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to import content from sharepoint into visual studio is to create site template from scratch and import it under visual studio as wsp solution.

A  good starting point : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231603.aspx